# How to remove "___" followed by the facet name from string after using reorder_within()?

Tags: r, facet-wrap

(I'm completely new to R)

I've used reorder_within() to reorder a variable within each facet of a bar plot, but this leaves "___" followed by the name of the facet group at the end of the string. I'm using ggplotly, so this appears in the hover info and looks unsightly (and too long). Is there a way to get around this still using reorder_within() or can I use a different function to reorder within facets?

I've already tried using gsub("___.*", "", column), but this removes the reordering.

```r
genepathways <- genepathways %>% mutate (Pathways = reorder_within (Pathways, -no_genes, Hallmark))

genepathwaysbp <- ggplot (genepathways)+
geom_col (mapping = aes (x = Pathways, y = no_genes, fill = Pathways))+
facet_wrap (~Hallmark, scales = "free")+
theme (legend.position = "none")+
theme (axis.text.x = element_blank ())+  #pathway names too long to fit, hence using plotly hover info to display this instead
scale_reordered_x()

(pp <- ggplotly (genepathwaysbp, tooltip = c("x", "y")))
```

Using similar code, it looks like this in each row and within the tooltip:
"pathwayname___facetgroupname". I would prefer if it just showed "pathwayname".

(for info, I used this: https://juliasilge.com/blog/reorder-within/)

Answer (score 8):

If you read Julia's post carefully, she includes the `scale_x_reordered()` from the `tidytext` package in her ggplot. This should remove the undesired facet group name.

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like `grep()` to find your string within your Pathways object. You can then use that information to find each instance of "pathwayname__facetgroupname" and replace it with what you want. Here's an example substituting your strings in:

```r
Pathways[grep("pathwayname__facetgroupname", Pathways)] = "pathwayname"
```

This should replace the name without messing with your ordering.